# Primera excepción del tipo 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' en mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, http

El error es por el siguiente codigo:

```
public Image GetAvatar(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(
                    string.Format("http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user={0}", username));
                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    return Image.FromStream(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { /*MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); */return null; }
        }
```

lo que quiero es que la cabecera HTTP se establezca un valor para UserAgent.
error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: subo la imagen mejor gracias compañero

Comment: perdona el fallo es otro lo subo ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
public Image GetAvatar(string username)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp(
            string.Format("http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user={0}", username));
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36";
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { /*MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); */return null; }
}
```

Utiliza el método `CreateHttp` en vez de create, y almacena el request como `HttpWebRequest` para tener acceso a la propiedad `UserAgent`.